# manage return type hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using native query to get data from database and add them into an object that content float values like:

```
select tons, delivered_tons from contract where id = 1
```

and using createSQLQuery() to execute the query

and return an object array like:

```
Object[] result = (Object[])query.uniqueResult();
```

and cast them into my object

```
A a = new A((Float)result[0],(Float)result[1]);
```

The problem is that I can't know the return type of the query (float or double). So do hibernate has any method to control the return type?

Answer (score 1):

If you used HQL instead os SQL, Hibernate would use the types that you chose to map the columns in your entity:

Assuming you have a Contract entity containing these fields:

```
@Entity
public class Contract {
    @Column(name = "tons")
    private Float tons;

    @Column(name = "delivered_tons")
    private Float deliveredTons;

    ...
}
```

You would simply execute the HQL query

```
select c.tons, c.deliveredTons from Contract c where c.id = :id
```

and you would be sure to get an array containing two Floats.

That said, for such a simple query, why don't you just use

```
Contract c = (Contract) session.get(Contract.class, id);
```

and then get the fields you want from the entity?

Comment: I'm using a complex query, like joining many tables and the results are not just the columns in the tables, it contains sum, average, etc. So I used native query instead of HQL (I don't have exp in writing HQL) The query that I mentioned above is just an example.